# Any reason for having "val capacity : Int" instead of "val Int Capacity" in Scala

Tags: scala, types, syntax, language-design

I am reading Scala and I am wondering ...
Why

```
val capacity : Int
```

instead of

```
val Int capacity.
```

Any reason why this choice was made. If not, it does not seem to me like a good choice to move away from the Java way of declaring it. Would have made the transition from Java to Scala easier (not by much, but little bit)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the majority of the time you can leave off the Int part. Scala has a much neater system of type inference than Java does.

Comment: If you add an example with and without the type it will make more obvious the reason.

Comment: Depends. Sometimes when the right hand site is complicated (especially when building APIs) you should annotate types as it catches many bugs at compile time.

Answer (score 10):

I think I read a statement by Martin Odersky himself somewhere saying that this decision was also made in order to improve readability. This is certainly the case, e.g. compare

```
val Double number = ...
val Array[(Seq[String], Map[Seq[String], Double])] something = ...
val String pattern = ...
```

with

```
val number : Double = ...
val something : Array[(Seq[String], Map[Seq[String], Double])] = ...
val pattern : String = ...
```

Most of the time you need to find *names* of references/mathods fast (visually), not types.

Answer (score 8):

x : T is the standard notation for types in logic and many programming languages. C and its descendants, with Java among them, deviates from this. But the type notation of C is really awful (try to write down the type for some moderately complicated higher order function like map).

Also, with this notation it is easy to leave out the type (as Wysawyg has already written), or to add a type inside an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to Wysawyg's statement:

```
val capacity = 2
```

But you typically might not do this with just a `val`.

```
trait Foo {
  def capacity = 2 // Allow child classes to override and decide the value later
}

// Force instances of Bar to set the value
class Bar( override val capacity : Int ) extends Foo

// Have Bat determine it on the fly
trait Bat extends Foo {
    def onlyAThird : Int
    override def capacity = onlyAThird * 3
}
```

(I tried to insert this as a comment, but alas, no formatting.)

Comment: Why do you use `def` for a literal constant? Further: `def` seems to be explained as `default` here, incidentally.

Comment: Ah, `def` is about about evaluation time. If we said `val capacity = 2` you couldn't let `Bat` extend `Foo` with a function that determines capacity on the fly.

Comment: I guess I understand now. You just define it as `def` to make it overrideable by a method. A val would only be overrideable by another val.

Answer (score 2):

In *Programming in Scala* it says the technical reason for this syntax is it makes the type inference easier.

Comment: How does placement of types alone make type inference easier? You can convert both to the exact same AST.

Answer (score 0):

I think Daniel thought of something like that:

```
val a = 7
val b: Int = 8 

var x = "Foo"
var y: String = "Bar" 

def sum (a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
def mul (a: Int, b: Int): Int = a * b
```

The type can often be inferred.