# Why does Scala choose to have the types after the variable names?

Tags: scala

In Scala variables are declared like:

```
var stockPrice: Double = 100.
```

Where the type (Double) follows the identifier (stockPrice). Traditionally in imperative languages such as C, Java, C#, the type name precedes the identifier.

```
double stock_price = 100.0;
```

Is it purely a matter of taste, or does having the type name in the end help the compiler in any way? Go also has the same style.

Comment: C, Java, and C# all derive from C. Pascal, for example, uses the same style as Scala.

Comment: Didn't know that about Pascal. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about closing this question with the intent of merging.  This one is far more likely to come up in a search unless the seeker is lucky enough that they just so happen to be asking about a variable named `capacity`.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin. Not only this question is better stated, but the answers are clearly superior -- and Odersky himself answered.

Comment: Remember that the colon is right-associative (if its the last character); so in that sense, the type still comes first. ;)

Comment: Besides Pascal, Golang is also using this style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any reason for having "val capacity : Int" instead of "val Int Capacity" in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891775/any-reason-for-having-val-capacity-int-instead-of-val-int-capacity-in-scal)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As well as supporting type inference, this has an ergonomic benefit too.

For any given variable name + type, chances are that the name is the more important piece of information.  Moving it to the left makes it more prominent, and the code more readable once you're accustomed to the style.

Other ergonomic benefits:

- With `val`, `var` or `def` before member names, instead of their type, they all neatly line up in a column.
- If you change just the type of a member, or drop it entirely in favour of inference, then a fine-grained diff tool will clearly show that the name is unaltered
- Likewise, changing between a val/var/def is very clear in diffs
- inference should be considered default behaviour in Scala, you only need type specifications in certain specific scenarios, even then it's mostly done for the compiler. So putting them at the very start of a declaration emphasises the wrong thing.
- "name: Type" instead of "Type name" more closely matches the way most programmers will actually think about a declaration, it's more natural.
- The differing C/C++ and Java conventions for pointers and arrays (i.e `*` being a prefix on the following name and not a suffix on the preceeding type in C/C++, or `[]` being a valid suffix on both names and types in Java) are still confusing to newcomers or language converts, and cause some very real errors when declaring multiple variables on a single line.  Scala leaves no room for doubt and confusion here.

Comment: I think it's also interesting to see that Java IDEs like Eclipse also display the name first. Not in the source code, but for example in the code outline.

Answer (score 68):

Kevin's got it right. The main observation is that the "type name" syntax works great as long as types are short keywords such as **int** or **float**:

```
int x = 1
float d = 0.0
```

For the price of one you get two pieces of information: "A new definition starts here", and "here's the (result) type of the definition". But we are way past the area of simple primitive types nowadays. If you write

```
HashMap<Shape, Pair<String, String>> shapeInfo = makeInfo()
```

the most important part of what you define (the name) is buried behind the type expression. Compare with

```
val shapeInfo: HashMap[Shape, (String, String)] = makeInfo()
```

It says clearly

- We define a value here, not a variable or method (val)
- The name of the thing we define is shapeInfo
- If you care about it, here's the type (HashMap[...])

Answer (score 15):

It's afterwards so that it can be removed for type inference:

```
var stockPrice: Double = 100.0
var stockPrice = 100.0
```

However, it is *not* true that imperative languages traditionally have types first. For example, Pascal doesn't.

Now, C does it, and C++, Java and C# are based on C's syntax, so naturally they do it that way too, but that has absolutely nothing to do with imperative languages.

Comment: Could you explain more on what you mean by "removed for type inference"? Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit Just look at the example, where the type was removed, so that it could be inferred.

Comment: I don't think type positioning in particular enables leaving them out.

Comment: @Raphael If it was written like in Java, `Double stockPrice = 10.0`, then removing the type would make it `stockPrice = 10.0`, which is not a declaration. In fact, C# had to introduce a keyword just to make type inference possible, which limits places where type can be inferred to places where the keyword may appear. In Scala, you just have to add or remove the type as desired.

Comment: Well, of course it can be a declaration: if the compiler can not find this identifier in its nametable, read the line as declaration. Yes, this might lead to messy code, but it is *possible*. Yes, this is a new case distinction, but you also have to handle two cases in Scala. So no, I do not see the difference.

Comment: @Raphael Since declarations can be nested and shadow out scopes, looking up a nametable won't work. Furthermore, since declarations can be pattern matching, which changes how symbols are processed, it could well be that a valid declaration could also be a valid expression, with two different meanings. Finally, if that were not the case, then C# wouldn't have done it.

Comment: ad 1: Nesting/scopes are already handled by compilers; it can be done by using a stack of symbol tables, for instance. Why would that change? ad 2: Pattern matching -- on this level! -- just introduces another scope. Also, do C, C++, Java, ... have pattern matching? ad 3: Now _that_ is a really weak argument! ;) Weird choices have been made by language designers forever: "It made sense, then."

Comment: @Raphael `{ x = 10.0; def f(y) = { x = 20.0; x * y }; f(5) * x}` -- what's the result? How can Scala know whether `x = 20.0` is a declaration or an assignment? That's the problem with nesting. Pattern matching: `Option(x) = y` -- is that assigning `y` to element `x` of `Option`, or is it assigning the result of extracting `y` through `Option` to `x`? Both things can be possible at the same time. As for "ad 3" -- sorry, but any decision made by any person involved in the evolution of C# has way more credibility than your own "it must be true" statements. Basically, C# > Raphael.

Comment: I now see the problem you have in mind. I will insist, though, that the problem not solvable without marking declarations is assigning scopes (amonst others); it is not type inference that is made hard by the positioning of the type (which you imply in your answer!). C# > me might be true, but that was not your statement (and the reverse not mine). You said "If A was possible, C# would do it, therefore A must be impossible". It is this precise statement I consider flawed, since even though C# > me, C# != opt.

Comment: @Raphael Type inference requires omitting type. If the type is used as a syntactical clue that a declaration is being made, the omitting it causes problems that have to be solved in some way. One way is to avoid using types as a syntactical clue. Thus, to enable type inference, Scala doesn't use types as a syntactical clue that a declaration is being made. And no one said anything about "not solvable". This is ONE solution, the one that was chosen.

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that even C doesn't "traditionally" define the type before the variable name, but indeed allows the declarations to be interleaved.

```
int foo[];
```

where the type for foo is declared both before and after it, lexically.

Beyond that, I'm guessing this is a distinction without a difference.  The compiler developers certainly couldn't care one way or another.

Comment: +1 just because this is a very unique observation about C syntax.  Makes me wish I'd taken Compiler Theory in college or read the dragon book...